# vercel deployment custom build

Tags: html, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a static html file using vercel. The issue is that the [github project](https://github.com/imfunniee/gitfolio) I got the html from uses custom build functions.

To run locally, I run the custom `gitfolio run` as the scripts in the package.json are

```
"scripts": {
    "cli": "OUT_DIR='./dist' node bin/gitfolio.js",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist/*",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,jsx,json,html,css,md}\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

which calls the run.js file from bin/gitfolio.js:

```
function runCommand(program) {
  let port = program.port ? program.port : 3000;

  app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/index.html");
  });

  app.listen(port);
  console.log(
    `\nGitfolio running on port ${port}, Navigate to http://localhost:${port} in your browser\n`
  );
}
```

So when I use the vercel CLI to build, I need to override the build command with `gitfolio run`, but that ends up getting stuck at

```
Gitfolio running on port 3000, Navigate to http://localhost:3000 in your browser
```

in the vercel build logs. Is there a way to hard code vercel to run my index.html file when it builds?